# "Error in G * t(hat) : non-conformable arrays" error in adonis(), in Vegan , in R

Tags: arrays, r, vegan

**ANSWERED:  A single NA value in any column in either `data.frame` can cause this error.**

---

I have a rather frustrating problem that I need help with.  I'm trying to run a permanova in R, and I'm using `adonis()` in Vegan to do it.  I have a species by sample `data.frame`, 249 rows by 16 columns (species names as `column.names`), and a separate `data.frame` of 249 rows by 3 columns, containing my environmental covariates.  I'm using the code below to run it, and I get the error above.  I've run adonis on some very, very similar data without issue, and I'm not sure what's wrong this time through.

Any suggestions? Thanks a ton.

---

#### Code

```
SpeciesADONIS <- adonis(ScreenedSpeciesbySample ~ AvgSalinity + AvgTurbidity +
        AvgDO + AvgSalinity * AvgTurbidity + AvgSalinity*AvgDO + 
        AvgTurbidity * AvgDO,
    data = RegPhysDriversTimeSeries2,
    permutations=999, method="bray")
```

#### Species by Sample head (created using `dput`)

```
ScreenedSpeciesbySample <- 
    structure(list(
        "Gulf menhaden" = c(0.05, 0.05, 0.01, 0.02, 0.00471, 0.01), 
        "Hardhead catfish" = c(0, 0, 0, 0.26, 0.00107, 0.04), 
        "White shrimp" = c(0.00298, 9.2e-06, 0.04, 0.13, 0.36, 0.01), 
        "Atlantic croaker" = c(0.01, 0.14, 0.44, 0.25, 0.08, 0.05), 
        "Black drum" = c(0, 0, 0, 0.12, 0, 0), 
        "Gafftopsail catfish" = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
        "Striped mullet" = c(0.46, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
        "Brown shrimp" = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.32, 0.04), 
        "Spotted seatrout" = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
        "Spot" = c(0.11, 0.41, 3.02e-05, 0.02, 0.00021, 0.00271), 
        "Gizzard shad" = c(0, 0.17, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
        "Red drum" = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
        "Bay anchovy" = c(0.00164, 0, 0, 0, 0.000127, 8.84e-05), 
        "Atlantic cutlassfish" = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, 0.49), 
        "Sand seatrout" = c(0, 0, 0, 0.04, 0.03, 0), 
        "Blue crab" = c(494.27, 583.35, 705.43, 476.09, 3103.18, 1699.67)), 
        .Names = c("Gulf menhaden", 
            "Hardhead catfish", "White shrimp", "Atlantic croaker", "Black drum", 
            "Gafftopsail catfish", "Striped mullet", "Brown shrimp", "Spotted seatrout", 
            "Spot", "Gizzard shad", "Red drum", "Bay anchovy", "Atlantic cutlassfish", 
            "Sand seatrout", "Blue crab"), 
        row.names = c(NA, 6L), 
        class = "data.frame")
```

#### Physical covariates head (created using `dput`)

```
RegPhysDriversTimeSeries2 <- 
    structure(list(
      AvgSalinity = c(14.88, 14.84, 5.7, 4.8, 9.5, 11.41), 
      AvgTurbidity = c(29.5, 53.53, 109.71, 109.48, 73.69, 39.37), 
      AvgDO = c(11.19, 8.18, 8.37, 14.39, 10.61, 7.94)),
      .Names = c("AvgSalinity", "AvgTurbidity", "AvgDO"), 
      row.names = c(NA, 6L),
      class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I can't replicate your problem, perhaps because your first data frame is missing some numbers for the first species (I just filled in some random values, and `adonis` ran fine). Generally the error you report would occur when the matrix containing your covariates, and the matrix containing your species have different numbers of rows. Make sure this isn't the case.

Comment: Mea culpa, I fixed the code in my example.  I have checked using both length(ScreenedSpeciesbySample[,x]) and the data descriptions in the RStudio workspace.  Both methods show me that both the drivers and species data.frame have 249 rows.  I'm at a loss for why this error is coming up.

Comment: Not reproducible with the snippet of data you included. Does it work for you with the snippet of data or is it an issue only with the larger set?

Comment: I just ran the exact same adonis using the snippets I sent, and it runs.  I'm genuinely confused now.  Should I include both full tables?  I'm hesitant to spam that many lines onto this page.  Suggestions for how I can find a solution to this issue would be much appreciated.  Thank you all very much for all your help so far.

Comment: In the full data set, are there missing values in either the covariate or species matrices that would cause a row to be dropped, when they are input into `adonis`?

Comment: There was a single NA value in row 217 of my physical covariate matrix.  The adonis() function is running now.  If we're ever at a conference together or you find yourself in Miami, I most definitely owe you a drink.